# Can the marketing cloud login session be used for landing pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, session, login, landing-page

I'm looking to create a landing page that allows Marketing Cloud users to check various data sources (data views, data extensions, etc.) for a specific subscriber. I understand how to do all this, but my concern is privacy. Realistically no one on the internet will figure out how to access the page, but it's a concern nonetheless. Should it be?

If so, is there a Marketing Cloud session variable to use to check log in status on the landing page? Is it possible to force that log in before accessing the landing page?

Comment: There's an option in Landing pages which is to create them as an application page which means it needs an authenticated user session to access. Explore that to see if that might be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option that Arvind referred to is called System Authenticated Redirection and more details about it can be found at:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/landing_pages/

It sounds like it is exactly what you are looking for.  While the default URL generated for a landing page is a long GUID that someone is unlikely to accidentally discover, it is a good idea to implement this option to prevent access to a page if it exposed any information that you wouldn't want public.

Comment: Are micro sites required to use this feature? Many of the options on that documentation page are not exposed when setting up a Landing Page (Content Type, Security, Publish Expiration Date...)

Comment: Yes, that feature along with some of the other advanced features are only available will full Microsite functionality, not the simplified Landing Pages option.